# VBA Macros Numero de filas, maximo de las sumas de fila , maximo de las suma de las columnas

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Necesito que el `VBA` me responda el **número de columnas**, el **máximo de la suma de las filas**, y el **mínimo de las sumas de las columnas**, de una tabla que cambia con numeros aleatorios.

La tabla ya esta programada para que de `Valores` y no funciones.

Como hago para programar para que me de las preguntas anteriores.

```
Sub generarMatrix()
ReDim Matrix(1 To 10, 1 To 10)
ReDim VectorSumasFilasMatrix(1 To 10, 1)

'Llena Matrix con valores dados
For i = 1 To 10
    For j = 1 To 10
       If Hoja5.Cells(i, j) = "" Then
               Matrix(i, j) = 0
        Else
                Matrix(i, j) = Hoja5.Cells(i, j)
        End If
        VectorSumasFilasMatrix(i, 1) = VectorSumasFilasMatrix(i, 1) + Matrix(i, j)
    Next j
Next i
```

---

Se supone que ya tengo la formula para las **sumas de la fila**, pero no se como poner que `VectorSumasFilasMatrix` me saque la fila que tenga la **mayor suma** y lo ponga en `Hoja1.Cells(45,5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Te he hecho un ejemplo que muestra lo que pides en la ventana Inmediato. Seguro que puede simplificarse, pero para lo que pides te sirve:

```
Sub Comprueba_Datos()
    
    Dim columnas As Integer
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim fila As Integer
    Dim columna As Integer
    Dim minimo As Integer
    Dim maximo As Integer
    Dim sumafilas As Integer
    Dim sumacolumnas As Integer
    
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    arr = sht.UsedRange
       
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        sumafilas = 0
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            sumafilas = sumafilas + arr(i, j)                
            If sumafilas > maximo Then
                maximo = sumafilas
                fila = i
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        sumacolumnas = 0
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            sumacolumnas = sumacolumnas + arr(i, j)
        Next i
        
        If minimo = 0 Then
            minimo = sumacolumnas
        ElseIf sumacolumnas < minimo Then
            minimo = sumacolumnas
            columna = j
        End If
        
    Next j
    
    
    Debug.Print "El máximo de filas es " & maximo & " y se encuentra en la fila " & fila
    Debug.Print "El minimo de columnas es " & minimo & " y se encuentra en la columna " & columna
    Debug.Print "Hay un total de " & UBound(arr, 2) & " columnas."

End Sub
```

En este ejemplo el resultado obtenido utilizando mis datos como ejemplo es este:

> El máximo de filas es 2694 y se encuentra en la fila 3
>
> El minimo de columnas es 1713 y se encuentra en la columna 4
>
> Hay un total de 9 columnas.